# Regex for football teams representing two participants playing against each other

Tags: c#, regex, data-annotations

My task is to have :

> EventName is a string representing two participants playing against
> each other.

I was thinking how can I do this with Data Annotation. So far I have this:

```
    [RegularExpression("^[^0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Name cannot contain numbers")]
    [Required, MinLength(10), MaxLength(150)]
```

I think I should only allow 1 delimiter( either "-" ":" or space) between those two teams. Anything else should not be allowed. No special characters, no numbers.

Could someone point me to the right direction?

Also does anyone know if football teams can have digits in their names?

Something like Villa1874 - Levski1914 ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To allow a single delimiter (`:`,`-` or single white-space, any can be surrounded by white-spaces) and numbers/underscores in the team names:

`^\w+ *[ -:] *\w+$`

Explanation:

- `^` asserts position at start of a line
- `\w+` matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_]) (1 or more)
- `*` matches any white-space (0 or more)
- `[ -:]` Match a single character present in the list
- `*` matches any white-space (0 or more)
- `\w+` matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_]) (1 or more)
- `^` asserts position at end of a line

Test: https://regex101.com/r/gBZDLE/6

If you don't want to allow numbers or underscores in the team names you can replace `\w` by `[A-Za-z]` instead:

`^[A-Za-z]+ *[ -:] *[A-Za-z]+$`

Test: https://regex101.com/r/gBZDLE/7

The previous doesn't allow spaces in the team names. To do so, you may want to match `[A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*` instead. This will match any name that starts with an alphabetic character and contain one or more words separated by single-spaces (e.g. "Manchester" or "Manchester United"). Full regex:

`^[A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)* *[ -:] *[A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*$`
Test: https://regex101.com/r/gBZDLE/5

Explanation of `[A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)`:

- `[A-Za-z]+` Match a single alphabetic character (`+` one or more times)
- `(?: [A-Za-z]+)` Non-capture group `(?: )`, matches a single white-space   followed by an alphabetic character one or more times `[A-Za-z]+`

Comment: Thank you but I want to allow only one dash or only one delimiter or none.

Comment: I've updated the answer to allow any of the delimiters. Although, I believe your problem says the name should contain two participants names, so a delimiter should be always present. If you want to remove the delimiter and allow only alphabetic characters you can just use: `^[A-Za-z]+$`

Comment: Manchester United - Tottenham HotSpurt will not work in this case. My idea was only one "-" sign and any spaces afte the first word(never in the beginning). I am sorry that I am so demanding but I am getting so frustrated with regex now :<

Comment: Updated answer to include white-space in between the team names, but doesn't allow to start or end with a white-space (anyway you could trim this out later when you process the input value in your code). It allows a single delimiter, that could be surrounded with zero or multiple white-spaces. I'd recommend you to keep playing with the regex until it suits your need.